# How to determine if the cin is keyboard or from file

Tags: c++, istream, ostream

I have an input function I'm writing:

```
void input(istream& ins)
```

As well as output function:

```
void output(ostream& outs)
```

My question is inside of these two functions, I want an if statement that determines if I'm writing from file or writing from keyboard. This is because inside of my input I am using the input to also cout statements if the data is not coming from a file.

I want my output file to determine if its writing to file, or its writing to the screen.
Basically, I just want to know how to check for writing from/to file if I want to pass the streams into the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a simple address compare:

```
if(&ins == &cin){
//then you using cin, since there is only one cin object
}else{
//other istream
}
```

same for cout...

```
if(&outs == &cout || &outs == &cerr){
//then you using standard outputs: cout or cerr
}else{
//other ostream
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Was thinking of something more complicated than that.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try this! Seems so simple, yet effective.

Comment: see my comment for cout

Comment: All of this seems to assume that the person didn't do `a.out > somefile.txt < someotherfile.txt`.

Comment: @Charlie I assume the question was how to know when using standard input/output when getting `istream` or `ostream` object. Even if standard input/output were redirected to file, it still the same, you are using `cin`, `cout`, `cerr` objects, which are unique.